# OK Button Dialogbox isn't working

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I use jQuery for dialogbox. it's strange when I tried to delete some element on it. when I click `ok` button. diaolog box won't redirect even close itself. nothing happen.

this is my first content contained in dialogbox and it works.

```
 <input type="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="indexbutton" onclick="book_tickets(this)" value="Book Seat" />
    <div id="dialog" title="Time Limit">
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>Name</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td><input type="text" id="txtName" value="" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> End of Time </td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="timepicker_7" value="01:30 PM" /></td>
           </tr>
       </table>

    </div>
```

when I tried to delete `txtName`, then `OK` button is not working or itsn't redirect to another page.
this is after I delete `txtName` element.

```
<table>               
           <tr>
               <td> End of Time </td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="timepicker_7" value="01:30 PM" /></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
```

this is how I write the dialogbox code

```
$(function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function () {
                ShowArrData(lObjSeat);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    ]
  });
});
```

and this is my showobjdata function

```
function ShowArrData(o) {
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    seatname = o[i].Name;
    time = jQuery('#timepicker_7').val();

    var guest = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    console.log(guest);

    var sid = btnId;
    if (sid == 'indexbutton') {
        var url = "CheckSeat.aspx?noSeat=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&endtime=" + encodeURIComponent(time);
        window.location.replace(url);
    } else {
        var url = "AdminCheckSeat.aspx?noSeat=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&endtime=" + encodeURIComponent(time) + "&guest=" + encodeURIComponent(guest);
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
   }
 }
```

my showobjdata flow is, if website accessed by index then go to checkseat.aspx else go to admin.

what's the matter ?

Comment: `var sid = btnId;` where is your `btnId`?

Comment: in another function. but it already global variables. I don't have problem with btnId. @Jai

Comment: whers the delete code.??

Comment: delete code ? I'm not talk about delete code. I mean, when I delete some element on dialogbox content it doesnt work. I''ve already put my after delete element @Outlooker

Comment: How are you deleting the elements inside the dialog and have you got any console errors..??

Comment: var guest = ...   will result in a null reference (as txtName is now gone). So trying to get its value from null will rightly result in the error

Answer (score 0):

replace `var guest = document.getElementById("txtName").value` inside clause `else`

because I put it out of `else`, so when condition is `guest=null` then showarrdata is didn't do anything.